# Adding a user-filled value as well as a pick value for google appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to define a field, where there is a list of allowed values as well as give user the option to type it in. For example, I list a bunch of previous jobs that the applicant can have, plus have them pick other and fill it in as well.

Is it possible to do this with one field or do I need two fields where the user has to type it in? Is there a doc. or sample or tutorial I can look up? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a super simple Tags sample:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxtQI4fTAVQqcUx4OUJfQ1JYV2c

To cover your exact use case you just need to:

1. Add logic to check if record already exists

   1.1 If record doesn't exist, then create one
2. Create relation between records

If you don't care about duplicates in your database, then you can skip step 1 and always do 1.1 and 2.

Comment: In my case, the field is part of a record, so let's say I have a company datasource, it has a field called company size, list of values I populate are, (small, medium, large). The user wants to come and put a new value in there when creating the company such as enterprise. It's a list of values as well as free populate.

Comment: I do understand your case, I thought that this sample can serve as good starting point to implement it. Do you a need more detailed one?

Comment: I have looked at sample but the sample creates a new record. I do not see a drop down where I can select a known list of values as well as add my own.